# Обрезать параметры URL

Tags: .htaccess

Изначально задача стоит сделать 301 редирект с `site.ru/info.php?do=&skip=0` на `site.ru/women/`, но удалось только перенаправить с `site.ru/info.php` на `site.ru/women/` таким образом:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_route_=info.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.ru/women/? [R=301,L]
```

Теперь осталось обрезать параметр `do=&skip=0` Пытаюсь сделать так

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^do= [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)info\.php $1? [R=301,L]
```

не работает. Подскажите как правильно. CMS ocStore 1.5.4.1

Опять же нерабочий вариант:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^do=
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php\?(.*)$ $1\.php [R=301,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

Два способа убрать запрос:

1. Поставить в конце URL, на который редиректите, символ `?`. Это будет интерпретировано как удаление запроса.

   ```
   RewriteRule ^from-path$ /to-path? [L,R=301]
   ```
2. Добавить флаг `[QSD]`. Тот же самый эффект. Требуется Apache 2.4+.

   ```
   RewriteRule ^from-path$ /to-path [L,R=301,QSD]
   ```

Если первый не сработал, попробуйте второй.